# Using a function inside a try...catch block how to exit the block?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When creating some endpoints using Node.js and express I came across a piece of code that is repeated a few times in the same controller file on different endpoints. This code is inside a conditional that is inside a try...catch block, it serves to validate if a sent parameter exists in the DB and so, if it exists or not, the execution proceeds accordingly. Here is my original code:

```js
const productListing = async (req, res) => {
    const { category_id } = req.query;
    try {
        // if there are query params execute this if statement
        if (req.url.includes("?")) {
            // the next 3 lines of code repeat a few times throughout the controller

            const validCategory = await knex("categories").where("id", category_id)
            if (validCategory.length === 0) {
                return res.status(404).json({ "message": "Category not found" });
            };

            const productsByCategory = await knex("products").where({ category_id })
            return res.status(200).json(productsByCategory);
        }; 

        const allProducts = await knex("products")
        return res.status(200).json(allProducts);
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ "message": "Internal error" });
    };
};
```

In order to improve the code and avoid repetition I tried to create the function below and call it instead of the repetitive code, what I expected to get was similar behavior, but although the function works when no query params are sent, or when the category exists, when the category does not exist, it makes the node crash and does not give the proper return, because in this condition the function should finish the try...catch block but the node tries to set the headers after the function has already done that.

FUNCTION:

```js
const validId = async (res, table, id) => {
    const validateId = await knex(table).where({ id })
        if (validateId.length === 0) {
            return res.status(404).json({ "message": `${table} not found` });
        };
    return 
};
```

MAIN CODE:

```js
const productListing = async (req, res) => {
    const { category_id } = req.query;
    try {
        if (req.url.includes("?")) {
            validId(res, "categories", category_id);

            const productsByCategory = await knex("products").where({ category_id })
            return res.status(200).json(productsByCategory);
        }; 

        const allProducts = await knex("products")
        return res.status(200).json(allProducts);
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ "message": "Internal error" });
    };
};
```

ERROR CODE:

```bash
    > nodemon ./src/index.js
    
    [nodemon] 2.0.22
    [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
    [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
    [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
    [nodemon] starting `node ./src/index.js`
    node:internal/errors:490
        ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
        ^
    
    Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
        at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
        at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:663:11)
        at ServerResponse.header (D:\CODING\CUBOS\BACKEND\unidade-5\desafio-backend-final-dbe-b2b-t03-ifood\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
        at ServerResponse.send (D:\CODING\CUBOS\BACKEND\unidade-5\desafio-backend-final-dbe-b2b-t03-ifood\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)
        at ServerResponse.json (D:\CODING\CUBOS\BACKEND\unidade-5\desafio-backend-final-dbe-b2b-t03-ifood\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:278:15)
        at validaId (D:\CODING\CUBOS\BACKEND\unidade-5\desafio-backend-final-dbe-b2b-t03-ifood\src\funcoes\validaId.js:6:36)
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
      code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
    }
    
    Node.js v18.15.0
    [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: You've removed a `return` here, so at the very least rewrite `validId` to return _something_ so that you the code that calls it knows whether a response was sent, so that if so, it can return early, the way it was doing before you rewrote it. That said: don't refactor express code like this. Instead, turn this into sequential middleware functions that may or may not call `next()` depending on whether more work should be done, and then chain your middleware functions in your app.get/post/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to `await` `validId`. Without `await` you can see that function actually gets executed *after* `productListing` returns. You can see `validId` was executed in the error stack trace - after a response was already sent.

You also need to know whether or not `validId` already returned a response, so you don't try to send a second response in the main function, resulting in the same error. You can do that by returning a boolean.

```js
const validId = async (res, table, id) => {
    const validateId = await knex(table).where({ id })
        if (validateId.length === 0) {
            res.status(404).json({ "message": `${table} not found` });
            return false;
        };
    return true;
};
```

```js
const productListing = async (req, res) => {
    const { category_id } = req.query;
    try {
        if (req.url.includes("?")) {
            // stop if not valid, validId will have responded already
            if (!(await validId(res, "categories", category_id)) return;

            const productsByCategory = await knex("products").where({ category_id })
            return res.status(200).json(productsByCategory);
        }; 

        const allProducts = await knex("products")
        return res.status(200).json(allProducts);
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ "message": "Internal error" });
    };
};
```

Comment: Although @derekaug [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76126236/11285599) is good, after fixing the missing `await`, I liked yours better because it was more concise, so I'll mark it as accepted , Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The

```
return res.status(404).json({ "message": `${table} not found` });
```

in the `validId` function is actually sending the response to the client but it never breaks execution of the function so then it goes on to the next

```
return res.status(200).json(allProducts);
```

and throws because the response has already been sent. You would need some way to determine that the response has already been sent by the `validId` function, if we kept things as they are currently. You could do something leveraging the `res.headersSent` property and not change too much of your code.

```
const productListing = async (req, res) => {
    const { category_id } = req.query;
    try {
        if (req.url.includes("?")) {
            await validId(res, "categories", category_id);
            if(res.headersSent) return;
            const productsByCategory = await knex("products").where({ category_id })
            return res.status(200).json(productsByCategory);
        }; 

        const allProducts = await knex("products")
        return res.status(200).json(allProducts);
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ "message": "Internal error" });
    };
};
```

I think things become a bit more clear if you keep the `validId` function fairly limited in its responsibilities and leave the response handling to the `productListing` function.

```
const validId = async (res, table, id) => {
    const validateId = await knex(table).where({ id })
    return validateId.length >= 0;
};

const productListing = async (req, res) => {
    const { category_id } = req.query;
    try {
        if (req.url.includes("?")) {
            if(!(await validId(res, "categories", category_id))) {
                return res.status(404).json({ "message": `Category not found` })
            }
            const productsByCategory = await knex("products").where({ category_id })
            return res.status(200).json(productsByCategory);
        }; 

        const allProducts = await knex("products")
        return res.status(200).json(allProducts);
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ "message": "Internal error" });
    };
};
```

Comment: You'll have to `await` `validId` or it will always be a truthy `Promise`

Comment: The first method you posted is very practical to solve the problem, the only thing missing was `await` before `validId` as @ChrisHamilton mentioned.